# how to redirect to a page and then force_download or vice-versa after login in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I am using CI and using force_download successfully. Now I want user to first login for download. So far so good and I am able to do it. The problem is when user isn't logged in on click of download it redirects to login page and then only do the download. Now I want is when  user logs in for download I want, 
1. to redirect to download page first and then do the force download
or 
2. do force download and then redirect to download page

How am I to do this. I tried redirecting to page after force download but to no avail. So far I don't want to use session. Any other option is highly welcome. Below is my function for download.

Thanks in advance.

```
function index($folder, $placeholer, $file){
            $this->load->helper('download');
            $fullname = $this->session->userdata('full_name');
            if(!empty($fullname)){
                if(file_exists("./administrator/uploaded_files/".$placeholer."/".$file)){
                    if($placeholer == 'article_files')
                        $tblName = 'tbl_articles';
                    else
                        $tblName  = 'tbl_discussion_papers';
                    $original_filename = $this->public_model->get_single_data($tblName, 'original_filename', $file);
                    $data = file_get_contents("./administrator/uploaded_files/".$placeholer."/".$file);     
                    force_download($original_filename, $data, $folder);
                }else{
                    echo "File doesn't exists.";    
                }
            }else{
                $data['login'] = 'Login first to Download';
                $data['class'] = 'error';
                $data['red_url'] = 'download/'.$folder.'/'.$placeholer.'/'.$file;
                //$data['downlod_url'] = $folder;
                $this->session->set_flashdata($data);
                redirect('login');
            }
        }
```

Comment: If the user is not logged in and clicks on the download button, then redirect the user to your login page and send a flag parameter `next` and `is_download` in the URL. I can show you the flow if didn't understood.

Comment: @ParagTyagi I don't want to change the URL as far as possible.

Comment: You don't have to change the URL, just you have to send parameter in get request. Ex. `redirect('login?next=download_page&is_download=yes')`.

Comment: Solution proposed by @ParagTyagi is the one you should follow. If you don't like change the URL, save the data in the user session.